# VBA or BATCH file to repair/compact Microsoft Access files in a folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a folder, with several subfolders, and inside of each one, there are several `ms access` files.

Currently, I open and `compact/repair` each one.

Could someone share some simple code to accomplish this programmatically?

It can do VBA inside `ms access`, Excel file, or a simple batch file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open each database file with a command line switch: **/compact**

It is documented here:

[Command-line switches for Microsoft Office products (Access)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Command-line-switches-for-Microsoft-Office-products-079164CD-4EF5-4178-B235-441737DEB3A6#ID0EAABAAA=Access)